# Displaying entire table from DynamoDB in AWS (Amazon web services)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have table "users" in Dynamodb in AWS (Amazon web services), I have 4 fields in the table. I want to display entire table in my page. I refered the AWS documentation, but I can't understand it. Anyone has any ideas to display entire dynamodb table in my page in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, you need to use the scan method.
Without any filter applied it will return all items and item attributes.

You can find more information about it here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html